# Mysql database connection details never work in included fle

Tags: mysql, connection-string

Whenever I use a seperate file to store DB connection details:

```
<?
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$database = "xxx";
?>
```

To use in my connection string, I can never get it to work. I have to embed the details in the connection string itself.

```
// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
if (!$connection) {
die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('xxx', $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why I have to do that? I'd really like to keep my details in a seperate file.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

```
include_once('path_to_the_file/db_details.php')
```

You have to include the file.

Additionally, please don't use MySQL, but MySQLi, or PDO. MySQL is deprecated and not maintained any more.